# How do I configure elastalert so it will connect to any server in the cluster?

Tags: elastalert

How do I configure elastalert so it will connect to any available server in the cluster? The [docs](http://elastalert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/running_elastalert.html#downloading-and-configuring) say:

> **es_host** is the address of an Elasticsearch cluster where ElastAlert
>   will store data about its state, queries run, alerts, and errors. Each
>   rule may also use a different Elasticsearch host to query against.

but every example I can find just points to one IP address or hostname.

I have tried using a list of hostnames such as `[elasticserver1, elasticserver2, elasticserver3]`, but that just causes elastalert to fail to start.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you would need a upstream load balancer to wrap up those es nodes.

In my case, I use nginx to do load balancing for my es nodes.  So the topology is something like this:

```
ElastAlert -> Nginx -> ES node 1
                    -> ES node 2
                    ...
                    -> ES node n
```

Sample nginx config

```
  upstream elasticsearch {
    server {node 1}:9200;
    server {node 2}:9200;
    server {node n}:9200;
    keepalive 15;
  }

  server {
    listen 8080;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://elasticsearch;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Connection "Keep-Alive";
      proxy_set_header Proxy-Connection "Keep-Alive";
    }

  }
```

Sample elastalert config.yml

```
es_host: "{nginx ip}"
es_port: "8080"
```

Here is the article I read about how to work with nginx
https://www.elastic.co/blog/playing-http-tricks-nginx

Answer (score -1):

As you identified in your answer elastalert targets a cluster not a node: "The hostname of the Elasticsearch cluster the rule will use to query."

Comment: But a cluster doesn't have an address, there are multiple servers in the cluster. If one server is not accessable I want it to use one of the other servers in the cluster similar to how logstash, kibana, or filebeat work.

Comment: from elastic: "A cluster is a collection of one or more nodes (servers) that together holds your entire data and provides federated indexing and search capabilities across all nodes. A cluster is identified by a unique name which by default is "elasticsearch". This name is important because a node can only be part of a cluster if the node is set up to join the cluster by its name."

Comment: from elastic: "A node is a single server that is part of your cluster, stores your data, and participates in the cluster’s indexing and search capabilities. Just like a cluster, a node is identified by a name which by default is a random Universally Unique IDentifier (UUID) that is assigned to the node at startup. You can define any node name you want if you do not want the default. This name is important for administration purposes where you want to identify which servers in your network correspond to which nodes in your Elasticsearch cluster."

Comment: Yes, I know what a cluster is. The cluster name is still not a network address that I can put in the elastalert config file. How do I tell elastalert to connect to any server in the cluster, not just one.

Comment: e.g. you could have an explicit coordinator node that manages the cluster or use implicit coordination. 

"The benefit of coordinating _only_ nodes should not be overstated — data nodes can happily serve the same purpose." 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-node.html#coordinating-only-node

Comment: The Elasticsearch client needs to be able to support load balancing. A coordinator is still single point of failure. The python client seems to support load balancing between nodes. So Elastalert guys would have to use it. And then you could just add the nodes you want to load balance to either coordinators or data or even ingest nodes.